# Wordpress Contact Form 7 datepicker change date format

Tags: wordpress, plugins, datepicker

I'm using `Contact Form 7` plugin in Wordpress, I would like some help in my `datepicker` on how to change the display date format in the front end in my form.
The default displays `mm/dd/yy` and I want to change it to `dd/mm/yy` but unfortunately I could not used this code:

```
dateFormat:dd/mm/yy
```

it seems it was not working.
I also tried to change the code in the plugin editor of datepicker but it did not work also.

Do you have any idea? an you help me how to change the date format without installing contact form 7 datepicker because I would like to use the default datepicker that include in the contact form 7.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the display date format to `dd/mm/yy` in the front end (also in the generated email) of my form by using plugin [Custom Datepicker NMR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-datepicker-nmr/) for Contact Form 7.

This allows you to use a new input field in your contact form called `[datepicker ]`

Install/activate the plugin and specify format date to show in the web browser like this:

```
[datepicker myFirstDatepicker id:myFirstDatepicker format:dd/mm/yy]
```

This plugin uses [jquery-ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Great, thank you, that worked... You should take care that you change date to "datepicker", which I forgot first... The id is also necessary, if including the form several times you have to give unique ids unfortunately, thus copying the form and giving unique ids is important then... But it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly for me. Try with no spaces: `date-format:dd/mm/yy`

So code for me in full for the line looked like this:

```
<p>
   Work Start Date (<span class="required">*</span>)<br />
   [date* start-date date-format:dd/mm/yy]
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do the configuration in the shortcode.

```
[date date-test date-format:dd/mm/yy]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already did that, actually my code now is date-format:dd-mm-yy but it didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't quite look like what I showed you. the date-test represents the name of the datepicker field. You should replace it with the actual name of your control. Also you did not put the leading date word in your shortcode. Try it exactly as I've shown but replace test-date with your control name.

Comment: I already tried. [date required-date date-format:dd/mm/yy class:view_input placeholder "my placeholder here"] but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I don't know where you got the `date-format` attribute from, but it doesn't work and also not documented

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score -3):

All you have to do is put:

```
[date your-date-from min:2017-01-01 max:2025-12-31 step:7 class:required "2017-01-01"]
```

Obviously put the dates you wish to use.