# Format date in contact form Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to know, how to change the date format in the contact form, if I am not wrong, it's the contact form 7.

For example: I have in one of the fields, Date of birth, but the format is shown like **jj/mm/aaaa**

I need to change it, in order to get this format in the field of the form **mm/jj/aaaa**. I want to clarify that it is not for the general settings, but for the contact form.

I've been checking around, but I haven't got any answer to my question, so probably you may help me.

Thanks to everyone and happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/) you can change the format with:

```
Administration > Settings > General > Date Format
```

There you should see something like this where you can change the format:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, it would be for the general settings, i'd need for the contact form specifically.

Comment: Okay so you don't want to change the format throughout the whole WordPress installation. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018682/wordpress-contact-form-7-datepicker-change-date-format) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually, I think that's right, but I don't know why the dashboard doesn't allow to modify anything. But yeah, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: Then I think it is rather a rights problem. [If the answer helped you, can you accept it so that others know that the answer helped you?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)